# Where is my code wrong which is causing each character to be on a new line?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, twilio

I wrote a simple script that will reach out to craigslist and look for Chevy S10 parts and then use Twilio to send me an SMS message with the ad titles. For some reason my texts come with each character in the title on a new line... Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from twilio.rest import Client

account_sid = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
auth_token = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
twilio_phone_number = '+12345678900'
my_phone_number = '+12345678900'

url = 'https://spokane.craigslist.org/search/sss?query=s10&sort=rel'
webpage = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage.text, 'html.parser')
body = []

datas = soup.find_all(class_ = "result-title hdrlnk", limit = 2)
for data in datas:
        body = 'New S10 Posts!\n' + '\n'.join(data.text)
        client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)
        client.messages.create (
                body = body,
                to = my_phone_number,
                from_ = twilio_phone_number
        )
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance

Comment: What's the value of `datas` at the for statement? Post it in your code snippet as a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here. If you take out the second "\n" character and make the `body` line instead be

```
body = 'New S10 Posts!\n' + data.text
```

Then the texts come with each character in the title on the same line.

Comment: Thank you. That worked exactly as needed. Next step is to get all the listings in 1 list that is sent in one sms message.